# Кроссплатформенность приложений Windows Forms (Monodevelop)

Tags: c#, кроссплатформенность, monodevelop

Создал в Ubuntu тестовый проект с помощью Monodevelop. Проект запустился без ошибок. Перенес это проект в Windows 10 и после установки gtk-sharp-2.12.45.msi открыл его в VS 2022. VS предложил сделать его проектом с Net Framework 4.8 и нормально загрузил.

Но при попытке создать приложение возникла ошибка:

> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "D:\MyProgramming\LinuxToWin\MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4\bin\Debug\MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe". Символы загружены.
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\gtk-sharp\v4.0_2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\gtk-sharp.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\glib-sharp\v4.0_2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\glib-sharp.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\atk-sharp\v4.0_2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\atk-sharp.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\gdk-sharp\v4.0_2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\gdk-sharp.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
> "MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: MonoDevUbuntu7.8.4.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll".

Сборка модуля выполнена без символов.
Вызвано исключение: "System.DllNotFoundException" в glib-sharp.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.DllNotFoundException" в glib-sharp.dll
Не удается загрузить DLL "libglib-2.0-0.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`
Я из библиотеки gtk-sharp к созданному в Debug exe-файлу добавил libglib-2.0-0.dll, но ошибка все равно появляется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно настроить проект в Windows, чтобы он работал. Проект - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/nmdG2krqlQHRzg

Comment: Под линуксы есть более мощные библиотеки, например Avalonia. А так, проще под Wine стандартное winforms приложение запустить, чем мучаться с непопулярными библиотеками.

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы. Откажусь от этой программы.